# Getting Dynamic Global config in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have Model `Setting` With table name `settings`

With following Fields

1. `Key`
2. `value`

`Key` Columns Will Contain the Unique Key

For Example `SITE_NAME`,`SITE_VERSION` etc.,

Now is There Any way to get the `value` of the  `key`

For Example `getSettings('SITE_NAME)`

I have Tried adding this to `service  provider`

```
foreach (Setting::all() as $setting) 
 {
  Config::set('settings.'.$setting->key, $setting->value);
 }
```

Now I have Tried by calling like

For Site name `config('settings.SITE_NAME')`

Its Works Perfectly

**BUT While Adding the Large Number Of settings it is taking So Long to Load the Application**

So Can Anybody `Suggest me a function` Like as Follows

> Store the values and keys and keys in **Cache**
>
> Refreshing the Cache Once the **Settings is Created or Deleted**

Comment: Be specific for what you want to retrieve

Comment: Do you have an Eloquent model set up for this table?

Comment: the title its so controversional its not even funny "dynamic constants"

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have created the helper function:

```
function settings($key) {
    $value = Cache::rememberForever('settings', function () 
    {
        return Setting::pluck('value', 'key');
    });
    return $value[$key];
}
```

And in the Blade file {{settings('key')}}